# Trying to grab ids from foreign keys in Rails 4 (with Mongodb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am writing a model in Ruby on Rails using MongoDB with mongoid.  I have three models: User, Store, Review.  A Review belongs to a User and Store.

```
class Review
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :rating, type: Float
  field :body, type: String

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store

  def self.is_unique
    where(user: user, store: store).exists?
  end

end
```

I am trying to find out if a User has already submitted a Review for a Store by looking to see if the Review contains the ids of Store and User.  However, I seem to be having trouble grabbing the ids from those foreign keys.  From the above code, I get this error message:

undefined local variable or method `user' for Review:Class

Strangely enough, if I add a user field and a store field, I get a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

With `def self.is_unique` you're defining a method on the Review class (to be called as Review.is_unique), not on Review instances. I believe what you want is to define `def is_unique`, so that you could do `Review.new(user: user, store: store).is_unique` and get a helpful answer.